# Why does `MakeBoxes` have the HoldAllComplete attribute and ignore it rather than HoldAll?

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, language-design

MakeBoxes has the attribute `HoldAllComplete`. For a normal function, it would imply that Upvalues should not be taken into account when the expression is evaluated:

```
In[1]:= G[F[x_]]^:=x^2 

In[2]:= G[F[t]]
Out[2]= t^2

In[3]:= Attributes[G]:=HoldAllComplete; G[F[t]]
Out[3]= G[F[t]]
```

However, if we evaluate the following code

```
In[1]:= MakeBoxes[Q[t_],f_]^:=SubscriptBox[t,"Q"]
In[2]:= MakeBoxes[Q[t]]
Out[2]= SubscriptBox[t,"Q"]
```

Also, in the notebook interface, we can see that the rule is used when `Q[t]` is formatted:
[image]

My question is then, why `MakeBoxes` does not have just the `HoldAll` attribute, which reproduces better how the evaluation is carried on?

Comment: `MakeBoxes` is meant to format _anything_. Compare `MakeBoxes[Evaluate[Print[1]]]` and `SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[Evaluate[Print[1]]]`.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the fact that MakeBoxes evaluation isn't like normal evaluation and inside MakeBoxes' evaluation, it ignores the HoldAllComplete attribute?

Comment: To what @GregHurst has said, I'd add that `MakeBoxes` seems to me the prototypical example of the reason why `HoldAllComplete` is needed at all, that is, why `HoldAll` isn't sufficient.